Golden ratio points in ellipse
This is a property of the ellipse. The sum of distances to the foci is constant:

In particular, some of these points must satisfy the golden ratio relationship:

Given the equation of the ellipse in standard form
$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$$
What are the coordinates of those "golden points" (The points on an ellipse where the ratio of the distances to the foci is  $\phi$) in terms of $a$, and $b$?

It is not clear to me what you are asking. What are the "golden points" you are referring to? The points on an ellipse where the ratio of the distances to the foci is $\varphi$?

the points where the distances to the foci are in the golden ratio relationship

Using polar coordinates,
$$r=\frac{b^2}{a-c\cos \theta}$$
which is focal-origin, namely
$$\frac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
Since $d_1+d_2=2c$,
\begin{align}
  \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} &= \frac{2c}{r} \\
  \sqrt{5}-1 &= \frac{r}{c} \\
  &= \frac{1-e^2}{1/e-\cos \theta} \\
  \cos \theta &= \frac{1}{e}-\frac{1-e^2}{\sqrt{5}-1}
\end{align}
The case of $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=\frac{2c}{r}$ is left as an exercise.

Given the equation of the ellipse in standard form:
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
where the foci are at $( \pm c, 0)$ and $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.
The distances between foci and the points are given by (distance formula):
$$
\begin{aligned}
& d_1=\sqrt{\left(x_i-c\right)^2+y_i^2} \\
& d_2=\sqrt{\left(x_i+c\right)^2+y_i^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
For $i=1,2,3,4$.
We want to find the points $(x, y)$ such that the ratio $\frac{d_1+d_2}{d_1}$ is equal to the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, or equivalently for which $\frac{d_1+d_2}{d_1}=\frac{d_1}{d_2}$. It is not hard to see from this equation that $d_1=\phi d_2$
From this we should be able to get an equation which we should be able to solve in tertms of a and b...

FYI: If $e:=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}/a$ is the ellipse's eccentricity, and $d:=a/e$ is the distance from its center to either directrix, then the "golden points" have $x$-coordinates $\pm\dfrac{d}{\phi^3}$.

It checks out!  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tyiijk9pit How did you find the exact solution? By directrix do you mean the line segments extending from the foci?

As it happens, analogous golden points on the hyperbola $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ have $x$-coordinate $\pm d \phi^3$ (where $e:=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}/a$  and $d=a/e$).

"How did you find the exact solution?" I solved the system (with the help of Mathematica, although the properties of $\phi$ make it reasonable to do by hand). I'll let you ponder it, and will post an answer if you don't get it on your own.

These are nice results :^)

It's convenient to use the eccentric parametric equations, $x=a\cos\theta, y=b\sin\theta$. With a bit of algebra, we see that the distance equations are perfect squares, so we get rid of those pesky square roots. Note that $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$.

Also, there's no solution unless $e\ge 1/\phi^3$.

@vallev: Oh, I missed your question about the directrix. By directrix, I mean a line used in conjunction with the focus and eccentricity to define the ellipse. See Wikipedia's "Eccentricity and directrix property" section of the "Ellipse" entry. I'll mention again that, for an ellipse (or hyperbola) with eccentricity $e$ and major/transverse radius $a$, the center-to-directrix distance is $a/e$, which is a nice counterpart to the fact that the center-to-focus distance is $ae$.

I see. Thanks for clarifying. My book only mentioned directrix for parabolas so I was puzzled. Either way, hail the kangleroo!
